# How many poison counters warrant an EDH loss?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mechanics

I tried Googling the answer, but it seems like different sources say different things, and I can't find anything about it in the Commander rules (on the official Commander website). My main takeaway is that it's arbitrary based on your playgroup, but it seems like a rather unsatisfying answer.

Does anyone know definitively how many poison counters it takes to kill someone in EDH?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is 10 just like in a normal game. The only format that changes the number of poison counters needed to cause a player to lose a game is Two-Headed Giant.

> **704.5c** If a player has ten or more poison counters, he or she loses the game. Ignore this rule in Two-Headed Giant games; see rule 704.5u instead.
>
> **704.5u** In a Two-Headed Giant game, if a team has fifteen or more poison counters, that team loses the game. See rule 810, “Two-Headed Giant Variant.”